# How to disable typescript rule in test file - React Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

New to react and I'm running into an issue where if I declare a type of `Enzyme.ReactWrapper` then I receive a compilation error for `Object is possibly undefined`. This is specifically when I use `Enzyme.mount` method. I'm also new to typescript and while my tests are passing, I get the error because `Enzyme.mount` can return undefined. What is the correct way to handle this?

```
let wrapper: Enzyme.ReactWrapper;
wrapper = Enzyme.mount(
    <AuthorQuiz {...(Object.assign({}, state, {highlight: 'correct'}))} onAnswerSelected={emptyHandler} />
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the JavaScript API that you are using within TypeScript, you need to explicitly declare the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) at the [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).
In your case you need to declare in the `tsconfig` the `es6` lib ([Object.assign](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/)), like:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
   "lib": ["es6"]
}
```

To solve `undefined` typing, if you are sure that the `Enzyme.mount` will return a instance, you can cast the returned value, like:

```js
let wrapper: Enzyme.ReactWrapper;
wrapper = Enzyme.mount(
    <AuthorQuiz {...(Object.assign({}, state, {highlight: 'correct'}))} onAnswerSelected={emptyHandler} />
) as Enzyme.ReactWrapper;
```

or declare and assign in the same line, and that way the variable type will be inferred:

```
const wrapper = Enzyme.mount(
    <AuthorQuiz {...(Object.assign({}, state, {highlight: 'correct'}))} onAnswerSelected={emptyHandler} />
);
```

If in the previous example, `wrapper` can be `undefined` on TypeScript, you can use it with the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) like `wrapper!.accessProperty`.